doc2docx docx2pdf back to back
I'm trying to convert .doc files to .docx or .pdf.
def file_handler(input_path, output_path=None):
    file_root, file_type = os.path.splitext(input_path)
    file_name = os.path.basename(file_root)
    local_working_directory = os.path.dirname(input_path)
    
    if file_type == '.doc':
        return_docx = os.path.join(local_working_directory, file_name + '.docx')
        #convert_doc_to_docx(input_path, return_docx)
        doc2docx.convert(input_path, return_docx)
        return file_handler(return_docx, output_path)
    
    elif file_type == '.docx': # docx.Document(input_path)
        return_pdf = os.path.join(local_working_directory, file_name + '.pdf')
        docx2pdf.convert(input_path, return_pdf)
        return file_handler(return_pdf, output_path)

When I try this (Or other implementations with win32), I keep getting:
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Word', 'Command failed', 'wdmain11.chm', 36966, -2146824090), None)

What's going on here? It converts to .docx successfully but then can't save to pdf. However, if I feed it a .docx, it converts to .pdf just fine. What's the issue with doing both? I saw this answer but the answers seem to provide manual fixes. I need to convert hundreds of files. Thanks.
Edit: I even get the error when using Pandoc to convert to .docx followed by docx to pdf:
subprocess.run([r"pandoc", sample_doc, '-o', os.path.join(current_path, 'sample_doc_to_docx.docx')])


What does import & export inside a controlled user session mean? And what does this mean for me? How should I convert these doc files to pdfs?
